# Syntax to put variable inside an if condition in a blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show an HTML containing variables if a condition was met, else just show "test" word.

```
<a href="/StuffSpot/notifPost/{{ $notification->id }}">{{ $notification->read == 1 ? '<strong>{{$notification->send_uname}}</strong> has commented on <strong>{{$notification->title}}</strong> post' : 'test' }}</a>
```

I'm receiving the following error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="/StuffSpot/notifPost/{{ $notification->id }}">
    @if($notification->read == 1)
        <strong> {{ $notification->send_uname }}</strong> has commented on <strong>{{ $notification->title }}</strong> post
    @else
        test
    @endif
 </a>
```

Try `if` `else` instead of one line Ternary Logic.

Also you have already used `{{  }}` to echo out, dont use `{{  }}` inside another, to display the html tags use `{!! !!}`, laravel blade `{{  }}` will escape and echo out the html tags inside these field